# Selecting Specific range bits from a bitset and displaying it

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, bitset, bitmask

Given a particular bitset<32>, how do I select and display the  m LSB bits of the bitset?
m is an integer value.

for example I have 10110111011110111101111011000100 and m = 8, the code should display 11000100.

Thanks

Comment: [Here's a documentation of the API](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: I tried shifting it and I was able to display 0000000000000000000000011000100. I'm trying to get rid of the 0s. I understand it's a juvenile question, but i'm just figuring out how to code.

Answer (score 4):

There's a fairly neat way to do this that many people don't immediately find obvious.

It depends on the fact that subtracting one from a number resets the least significant bit that's currently set, and sets all the less significant bits.

So, ignoring the `bitset` part for the moment, and dealing only with some integer type, we can do something like this:

```
unsigned x = 0b10110111011110111101111011000100;

unsigned m = 8;

unsigned mask = (1 << m) - 1;

unsigned result = x & mask;
```

I'll leave it to you to render the same basic idea in `std::bitset` operators.

If your intent is to display a bitset without the leading zeros, well...sorry, but it doesn't support that directly, so if you do something like this:

```
std::bitset<15> x;

std::cout << x;
```

You'll *always* get exactly 15 characters of output, regardless of how many (or few) of those happen to be zeros. It is pretty easy to write code to skip the leading zeros on your own though (or to write the `bitset` to a `stringstream`, then trim off the leading zeros).